# Kendo UI ASP.Net Pie Chart Exploded Section

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, kendo-ui

I am looking for an example in either C# or VB Razor syntax for a pie chart with an exploded section. I am not binding individual fields, I am using something like...

```
.Series(Sub(series)
      series.Pie(Function(model) model.Id, Function(model) model.PriorityName).Overlay(ChartPieSeriesOverlay.None)
End Sub) _
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through support demos and support from Telerik I have figured this issue out. Hopefully this helps someone some day. I added another parameter to my ViewModel that just passes a boolean if I want the piece of the chart exploded. Then I pass that into the code below as Model.Explosion.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Of Core.UI.PieChartViewModel) _
        .Name("Chart_OpenItemsByPM") _
        .ChartArea(Function(c) c.Background("#fff")) _
        .HtmlAttributes(New With {.Style = "height:280px;width:90%;margin:0px auto;"}) _
        .Legend(Function(legend) legend.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)) _
        .DataSource(Function(ds) ds.Read(Function(r) r.Action("Chart_OpenItemsByPM", "Dashboard"))) _
        .Series(Sub(series)
                        series.Pie(Function(model) model.Id, Function(model) model.Priority

Name, Nothing, Function(model) model.Explosion).Overlay(ChartPieSeriesOverlay.None)
                    End Sub) _
            .SeriesColors("#c72e15", "#c78215", "#c7c115", "#156dc7") _
            .Tooltip(Function(tooltip) tooltip.Visible(True).Format("{0} Tickets"))
        )
```